# How can I get VS Code LaTeX Workshop to choose the correct Latex distribution?

Tags: pdftex, compiling, texlive-2020

I have installed two Latex distributions on my PC, i.e., Ctex and Texlive 2020. VS Code LaTeX Workshop keeps using Ctex to compile latex files. How do I force VS Code to compile with Texlive 2020?

For some reason, I need to keep the Ctex on this PC. My settings.json of VS Code LaTeX Workshop is as follows. In particular, I have specified the path of Texlive 2020. However, it still cannot compile with Texlive 2020.

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

    {
    "name": "xelatex",
    "command": "xelatex",
    "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "-pdf",
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ],
    "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2020"}
    },
    {
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "command": "pdflatex",
    "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ],
    "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2020"}
    },
    {
    "name": "bibtex",
    "command": "bibtex",
    "args": [
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ],
    "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2020"}
    },
    {
    "name": "biber",
    "command": "biber",
    "args": [
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ],
    "env": {"TEXMFHOME": "c:/texlive/2020"}
    }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
    "name": "pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "pdf->biber->pdf->pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex",
    "biber",
    "pdflatex",
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "pdf->bibtex->pdf->pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex",
    "bibtex",
    "pdflatex",
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    }
    ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution from [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/433542505).
Changing "command" instead of "env" in the settings.json file of VS Code works for me.

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

    {
    "name": "xelatex",
    "command": "C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/xelatex.exe",
    "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "-pdf",
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "pdflatex",
    "command": "C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/pdflatex.exe",
    "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "bibtex",
    "command": "C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/bibtex.exe",
    "args": [
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "biber",
    "command": "C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/biber.exe",
    "args": [
    "%DOCFILE%"
    ]
    }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
    "name": "pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "pdf->biber->pdf->pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex",
    "biber",
    "pdflatex",
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "pdf->bibtex->pdf->pdf",
    "tools": [
    "pdflatex",
    "bibtex",
    "pdflatex",
    "pdflatex"
    ]
    }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Ubuntu 18.04/20.04, follow steps below:

1. Add `PATH` variable to the environment:

```bash
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin:$PATH
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

Source your bash config.

2. Close all VScode windows. Restart VScode.
   This works in my system. Hope it also helps you.

Comment: This worked for me on Mac Monterey 12.6.3. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Latex Workshop supports to customize latex executable per file in shebang, like below:

```tex
%!TeX program = /Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
% ...
```

**Update**: For the above to work, `latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage` have to be set to `False`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, LaTeX Workshop recently disabled this feature unless you switch `latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage` to False.

Comment: @Miyase Thanks you are right. I have been using 8.21, while this flag has to be turned off in the latest version. I will update this answer.