# Texlive / LatexWorkshop - unable to Build or Preview Latex Files

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have installed TexLive on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

After this I created a file "text.tex" in Visual Studio Code. I installed the Plugin "Latex Workshop" and tried to preview or Build the .tex File.

I received the following error:

```
Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT.
```

According to this:

```
https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1742
```

The reason for this is, that something is wrong with the PATH Variable

I am not sure whether TexLive is actually included in my PATH:

Using echo $PATH yields:

```
/home/tony/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/mssql-tools/bin
```

I can use latex-v and which latex yields:

```
/usr/bin/latex
```

TexLive itself is located at:

```
/usr/share/texlive
```

I have tried to debug this by following the advice from the github page - I copied the content of m PATH variable into the "env" fields in the settings.json of LatexWorkshop, however, the error persists.

Someone solved a fairly similar problem here:
[How can I get VS Code LaTeX Workshop to choose the correct Latex distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573995/how-can-i-get-vs-code-latex-workshop-to-choose-the-correct-latex-distribution) This was on Windows however.

I am not sure whether something is wrong with my TexLive installation, my PATH variable or something is buggy or falsely set up within VSCode/LatexWorkshop.

Comment: Have you checked that you actually have `latexmk`? Ubuntu breaks texlive up into a number of Ubuntu packages (not to be confused with latex packages). You can use the `apt-file` tool to figure out which Ubuntu package provides `latexmk` (`apt-file search latexmk`), I think it is called `latexmk`. Note that `apt-file` needs `sudo apt-file update` from time to time.

Comment: @daleif That was just it. Just reinstalled it using sudo apt-get install latexmk. Now everything works as intented. TY!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Ubuntu TeXLive is split into many Ubuntu packages (not related to LaTeX packages). Some of the software tools that come with TeXLive are also split into their own Ubuntu packages. And since installing the Ubuntu `texlive` package does **not** install everything TeXLive relatated, chances are that you are missing something.

In this case the Ubuntu package `latexmk` provides the `latexmk` tool.

I looked it up via `apt-file search latexmk`. Note that other Ubuntu packages match as well but that is mostly `latexmkrc` configuration files.

Note if you use the `apt-file` tool, remember to run `sudo apt-file update` from time to time. This updates the file lists that `apt-file search` searches.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this issue (MacOS):

**Step1:** reinstall maxtax by downloading it from this link: http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

**Step2:** In your terminal do `cd /usr/local`, you should see texlive folder

**Step3:** In your terminal do `sudo vim etc/paths` to set the environment. Details are in this link: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

**Step4:** In your terminal do `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` at the bottom. check the folder to see if the year is correct. Details in: http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html.

**Step5:** Quit VC code completely, and reopen it.