# Latex Workshop error: Cannot find LaTeX root file

Tags: installing, ubuntu, vscode, latex-workshop, root

I recently changed from Windows to Ubuntu because I'm learning to code. I used to write my class assignments in LaTeX using vscode and Latex Workshop. However, I've tried to set it up in Ubuntu and I've run into multiple errors. I have been able to solve (or at least I think I have) every of them, but I'm unable to solve this last one.

The problem is the following: when trying to build the latex proyect the terminal shows this:

```
[19:17:56.309][Commander] BUILD command invoked.
[19:17:56.310][Commander] The document of the active editor: file://%WS1%/main
[19:17:56.310][Commander] The languageId of the document: latex
[19:17:56.310][Manager] Current workspace folders: ["file://%WS1%"]
[19:17:56.311][Manager] Found root file from active editor: %WS1%/main
[19:17:56.311][Manager] Keep using the same root file: %WS1%/main
[19:17:56.312][Event] ROOT_FILE_SEARCHED
[19:17:56.312][Commander] Cannot find LaTeX root file. See https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#the-root-file
[19:17:58.322][Cacher] Error loading cache: %WS1%/main . Forcing.
[19:17:58.328][Structure][LaTeX] Error loading content during structuring: %WS1%/main .
[19:17:58.330][Structure] Structure updated with 0 root sections for %WS1%/main .
[19:17:58.333][Event] STRUCTURE_UPDATED
```

and nothing happens. When I open vscode, it shows this:

```
[19:17:31.034][Logger] New log placeholder %WS1% registered for /home/alejandro/Documentos/latex/tfm .
[19:17:31.034][Config] latex-workshop.latex.tools: things-that-flagged-the-question-as-spam.
[19:17:31.044][Config] latex-workshop.latex.outDir: "%DIR%/build" .
[19:17:31.085][Manager] Set $LATEXWORKSHOP_DOCKER_LATEX: ""
[19:17:31.093][Server] Creating LaTeX Workshop http and websocket server.
[19:17:31.142][Server] Server successfully started: {"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":41019} .
[19:17:31.164][Extension] Initializing LaTeX Workshop.
[19:17:31.164][Extension] Extension root: /home/alejandro/.vscode/extensions/james-yu.latex-workshop-9.15.0
[19:17:31.164][Extension] $PATH: /home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/latex/bin:/home/alejandro/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
[19:17:31.165][Extension] $SHELL: /bin/bash
[19:17:31.165][Extension] $LANG: en_US.UTF-8
[19:17:31.165][Extension] $LC_ALL: undefined
[19:17:31.165][Extension] process.platform: linux
[19:17:31.165][Extension] process.arch: x64
[19:17:31.165][Extension] vscode.env.appName: Visual Studio Code
[19:17:31.166][Extension] vscode.env.remoteName: undefined
[19:17:31.166][Extension] vscode.env.uiKind: 1
[19:17:31.166][Extension] LaTeX Workshop initialized.
[19:17:31.173][Format][Bib] Bibtex format config: {"tab":"  ","case":"lowercase","left":"{","right":"}","trailingComma":false,"sort":["key"],"alignOnEqual":true,"sortFields":false,"fieldsOrder":[],"firstEntries":["string","xdata"]}
[19:17:31.174][Extension] Trigger characters for intellisense of LaTeX documents: ["\\",",","{"]
[19:17:31.176][Manager] Current workspace folders: ["file://%WS1%"]
[19:17:31.176][Manager] Found root file from active editor: %WS1%/main
[19:17:31.177][Manager] Root file changed: from undefined to %WS1%/main
[19:17:31.177][Manager] Start to find all dependencies.
[19:17:31.177][Manager] Root file languageId: undefined
[19:17:31.177][Event] ROOT_FILE_CHANGED: "%WS1%/main"
[19:17:31.178][Cacher][Watcher] Reset.
[19:17:31.183][Cacher] Adding %WS1%/main .
[19:17:31.185][Cacher][Watcher] Watched %WS1%/main with a new watcher on %WS1% .
[19:17:31.185][Event] FILE_WATCHED: "%WS1%/main"
[19:17:31.186][Event] ROOT_FILE_SEARCHED
[19:17:31.187][Cacher][Path] Non-existent .fls for %WS1%/main .
[19:17:31.298][Server] valdOrigin is http://127.0.0.1:41019
[19:17:35.047][Cacher] Error loading cache: %WS1%/main . Forcing.
[19:17:35.055][Structure][LaTeX] Error loading content during structuring: %WS1%/main .
```

Now I will enumerate the things I have done to get to this point:

1. I first tried to follow [TexLive documentation for quick install](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

   1. I created a texlive directory in home
   2. I executed there all the commands in the docs until I got an error on `cd install-tl-*`, which for I had to write its full name.
   3. I tried to update the PATH without success.
2. Updating PATH: I saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root) people having the same problem. I followed the instructions from some of them without success. I tried to do it via the tlmgr gui, again `echo $PATH` was not showing texlive.
3. I followed [Ubuntu's doc for encitomental variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and created a `myenvsvars.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/` and put `export PATH=$PATH:/my/which/pdflatex/` there. I finally got texlive in PATH, as shown here:

```
/home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/latex/bin:/home/alejandro/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

5. Installed `latexmk` via `sudo apt install latexmk`.
6. After solving this, I ran into the error I am posting, and tried (just in case) to add the PATH to the env latexworkshop as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691386/vscode-texlive-latexworkshop-unable-to-build-or-preview-latex-files-unable). Now my `latex-workshop.latex.tools` looks like this:

```
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape",
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin"}
```

for every env. This didn't really alter the output.

7. (added later) I am able to compile latex in terminal.

I think this is pretty much all I have to say. I have used some commands in between from the pages I posted, but I don't really know how those could have messed up the later ones. I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and I'd highly appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! I suspect you have multiple TeX installations and possibly some other complications. Did you literally write `export PATH=$PATH:/my/which/pdflatex/`? For example, the equivalent snippet from my profile script is `export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/bin:${PATH}"`. Can you compile a simple `tex` file on the command line? If not, what error do you get? What is in `/home/alejandro/anaconda3/envs/latex/bin` and `/home/alejandro/anaconda3/condabin`? Those are prepended to PATH in vscode. How did you install vscode and latex workshop?

Comment: 1. I wrote ```export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"```, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 2. I am able to compile a simple ```tex``` and turn it into a pdf in terminal, I just did it with the example [here](https://guides.lib.wayne.edu/latex/compile).

Comment: 3. I can't see any ```/bin``` in my latex enviroment directory. In ```/condabin``` there is only a file called ```conda```.
4. I installed vscode by terminal and latex workshop was installed as the synchronizing started, as I had it installed in my previous set up.

Comment: Is `/home/alejandro/Documentos/latex/tfm` your working directory? `Is `main.tex` your main TeX file? Because I guess that's what it is looking for.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with latexworkshop, but there are things in your `latex-workshop.latex.tools` look odd. Under Windows, environment variables are things like `%PATH%`, but the same variable under Linux is `$PATH`. You may need to check what the tool expects.

Comment: With regards to the comment from @cfr, you can see if you have multiple LaTeX installs with something like this: `sudo updatedb ; locate pdflatex` which should show only one file named exactly `pdflatex` (there are likely others, including a manpage `pdflatex.1.gz`). If you have more than one, you may have multiple installs. This will lead to some problems, unless you know what you are doing, and are careful. There are some solutions which can be found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/678711 (Advanced topic, at the end) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/676877 and questions linked from that.

Comment: @enkorvaks I don't think those are supposed to be environmental variables. I think they are variables the *editor* uses. It's very common for editors to use `%` for variables they will supply. At least, it is common on Linux and Mac. If Windows uses that for environmental variables, perhaps they use something else on that platform. For example, Kile uses `%` in this way so scripts can make use of information provided by the editor e.g. the filename or the selected text or whatever.

Comment: `which -a pdflatex` may give more manageable output than `locate`. On my machine, `locate pdflatex` returns 192 results, including 5 exact matches. `which -a pdflatex` returns 2 (and those are identical).

Comment: @cfr you may be right, which is why I specified I didn't know the tool. It looked odd to me, but may be correct. I have seen quite a number of different templating markers, but I know Windows (and DOS before it) used `%NAME%` and don't recall that anywhere else.  I also made this suggestion because Alex Moreno has moved from Windows to Linux, and I suspected that the files might have been using Windows variables, and were copied to Linux without change (and now don't work). I am content to be wrong about that, though (if I am wrong, then I have learnt something today).

Comment: @enkorvaks i don't know the tool either. But I'm using Kile on Linux, which uses `%` for variables. (Of course, not for environmental variables.) And I *think* TeXShop did the same on Mac, but it's a long time since I've used a Mac. So I'm familiar with this and I've never used a TeX editor on Windows. Plus `New log placeholder %WS1% registered for /home/alejandro/Documentos/latex/tfm .` looks as if it might be an assignment by the editor rather than a configuration setting. Moreover, I'd expect syntax errors if `%` wasn't intercepted by the editor.

Comment: Hi again, I was away from my house for some days and cound't answer. @cfr ```/home/alejandro/Documentos/latex/tfm ``` was indeed the working directory. ```which -a pdflatex``` shows 4 locations: ```/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex```, ```/usr/local/bin/pdflatex```, ```/usr/bin/pdflatex```, ```/bin/pdflatex```.

Comment: You have multiple installations of TeX. This can cause problems unless you are very careful. In particular, it's generally best to either install vanilla TeX Live from upstream or to install your Linux distro's packages. Having different versions of vanilla installed simultaneously is generally fine, but mixing one or more of those with Ubuntu's packages probably means trouble. Either remove the installation in `/usr/local/texlive` and make sure all relevant Ubuntu packages are installed or uninstall Ubuntu's and replace with a 'dummy' package to satisfy your package manager.

Comment: What can I do to specify the PATH to Latex Workshop after removing? I preserved Ubuntu's one. Now ```which -a pdflatex``` shows ```/usr/bin/pdflatex``` and ```/bin/pdflatex```.